# Why use elimination method vs. substitution method in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, substitution, gaussian-elimination

What is the motivation to use the elimination method as opposed to the substitution method? I've always found the latter much easier. Are there any examples where the substitution method fails or when it is inferior to the elimination method?

For an example of the substitution method see:

[Substitution method review (systems of equations)](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/x2f8bb11595b61c86:systems-of-equations/x2f8bb11595b61c86:solving-systems-of-equations-with-substitution/a/substitution-method-review-systems-of-equations)

Comment: If you mean for solving a system of linear equations, the elimination method (i.e. row reduction) is closely related to other matrix computations which are useful for solving many different types of problems, whereas substitution is mostly good for one thing -- finding solutions to a systems of equations. In other words, the method of elimination generalizes to other sorts of problems in ways that substitution does not.

Comment: @Curious It's clear that the "elimination method" refers to [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination). However, it is not clear what you mean by "the substitution method"; please explain what you mean

Comment: @Curious Perhaps you mean something like this: we take the system of $m$ equations on $n$ variables and 1. select one equation and one variable, 2. solve the chosen equation for the chosen variable in terms of the remaining variables, then 3. substitute this expression for the chosen variable into the remaining equations to produce a system of $m-1$ equations on $n-1$ variables.  If that's what you mean, then you should know that this is essentially what Gaussian elimination does (except that our choice of variable in step 1 is constrained).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the elimination method is equivalent to the substitution method, where the choice of the variable for which we solve is constrained.

**Example:** Consider the $3 \times 3$ system
$$
\begin{cases}
x + y + z = 2\\
x + 2y + 3z = 5\\
x + 4y + 9z = 15
\end{cases}
$$
With elimination, we would proceed as follows:
$$
\pmatrix{1&1&1&2\\
1&2&3&5\\
1&4&9&15} \leadsto
\pmatrix{1&1&1&2\\
0&1&2&3\\
0&3&8&13} \leadsto
\pmatrix{1&1&1&2\\
0&1&2&3\\
0&0&2&4} \leadsto 
\pmatrix{1&1&1&2\\
0&1&2&3\\
0&0&1&2}.
$$
At this point, we see that the original system of equations can be rewritten as
$$
\begin{cases}
x + y + z = 2\\
\quad \ \  y + 2z = 3\\
\quad \ \ \quad \ \ z = 2.
\end{cases}
$$
If we solve the first equation for $x$, substitute, solve the first of the resulting two equations for $y$, then the result is exactly the same. In particular,
$$
x+y+z = 2 \implies x = 2-y-z.
$$
Substituting this into the second and third equations yields
$$
\begin{cases}
(2-y-z) + 2y + 3z = 5\\
(2-y-z) + 4y + 9z = 15
\end{cases} \implies
\begin{cases}
y + 2z = 3\\
3y + 8z = 13.
\end{cases}
$$
This is exactly what we have after the first step of elimination. Solving the second equation gives us
$$
y + 2z = 3 \implies y = 3 - 2z,\\
3(3-2z) + 8z = 13 \implies 2z = 4.
$$
This is exactly what we have after the second step of elimination.

Comment: So its rather intuition to use one method over the other??

Comment: @CuriousIndeed Yes; the only real difference between the two methods is that substitution is more intuitive. Elimination is also faster in that there is no real need to write and rewrite the variable-names $x,y,z,$ which isn't much trouble with $2$ variables but becomes tedious for larger systems of equations.

Answer (score 1):

There are two aspects which makes the substitution method inferior to the elimination method, and vice versa.

1. Many people prefer one method to another method due the personal preferences.
2. The original problem  is made to be solved with one method.

In my case, I do prefer the elimination method. So I first of all I look whether the linear equation system can be solved with this method easily or not. An example:

$2x+y=5$

$4x+y=9$

Here it is easy to see that this system can be solved with the elimination method. We just subtract the first equation from the second equation in order to eliminate $y$.

$2x=4\Rightarrow x=2$

But in another case I would use the substitution method due the structure of the equations:

$\frac23u+4v=14$

$u+v=6$

The second equation can be easily solved for u: $u=6-v$. This equation system might be a case where I would apply the substitution method, although I generally prefer the elimination method.

$\frac23\cdot (6-v)+4v=14$

$4-\frac23v+4v=14$

$-\frac23v+\frac{12}3v=10$

$\frac{10}3v=10\Rightarrow v=3$